# Use of UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a small imageView that moves on the screen using the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but when it comes out from the edges of the superview does not get more touches and therefore can no longer turn back. How can I prevent that the image comes out from the edges of the superview?
 This is the code:

```
- (void)pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
if (inLongPress) {
    UIView *hitView = [gestureRecognizer view];

    [self adjustAnchorPointForGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    if (!(CGRectContainsRect(self.imageView.frame, hitView.frame))) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"" context:NULL];
        [hitView setCenter:CGPointMake(_prevCenter.x, _prevCenter.y)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

     }
    _prevCenter=hitView.center;

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || [gestureRecognizer   state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[hitView superview]];

        [hitView setCenter:CGPointMake([hitView center].x + translation.x, [hitView center].y + translation.y)];

        [gestureRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:[hitView superview]];
    }

    if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
        inLongPress=NO;
        hitView.alpha=1.0;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a couple of `if` that limit the CGPoint to an allowed range.

Something like this makes sure that you can't move the object outside of the view:

```
CGFloat proposedX = location.x;
CGFloat proposedY = location.y;

CGRect objectFrame = hitView.frame;
CGFloat allowedXMin = 0 + objectFrame.size.width / 2.0f;
CGFloat allowedXMax = self.view.bounds.size.width - objectFrame.size.width / 2.0f;
CGFloat allowedYMin = 0 + objectFrame.size.height / 2.0f;
CGFloat allowedYMax = self.view.bounds.size.height - objectFrame.size.height / 2.0f;

if (proposedX < allowedXMin) {
    proposedX = allowedXMin;
}
else if (proposedX > allowedXMax) {
    proposedX = allowedXMax;
}

if (proposedY < allowedYMin) {
    proposedY = allowedYMin;
}
else if (proposedY > allowedYMax) {
    proposedY = allowedYMax;
}
location = CGPointMake(proposedX, proposedY);

hitView.center = location;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your viewDidLoad method of your view controller , just set the **clipsToBounds** property of your superview to **YES**.

`[superview setClipsToBounds:YES];`